# Problem similar to Gambler's Ruin

Tags: probability, gambling

I am working on a problem that is similar to the gambler's ruin problem.

> We start with a bet of $\$1$.
>
> - With probability $p$ the game is won and we win the amount of the bet, i.e., if we bet $\$1$, we win $\$2$.
> - With probability $1-p =: q$ the game is lost.
>
> If we win the game,  we take our earnings and stop playing. If we lose we double our bet and keep on playing until we lose.
>
> What is the expected amount we bet in total?

I would argue that the formula for the total bet looks like this, but I'm not sure if I made a mistake somewhere, as it would give negative bet values for a small $p$.

$$\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(2^k-1)p(1-p)^{(k-1)}=\frac{2p}{2p-1}-1$$

Many thanks for your time and help!

Comment: I'm not sure we mean the same thing by "the winnings are twice the amount of the bet."  If I start with one dollar, and win the first bet, do I now have two dollars or three dollars?

Comment: 2 dollar, how would you say that in english, so i can clarify it in the text

Comment: "You win the amount of the bet" is what I would say, but I'd also give an example to be sure it's clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your sum into two separate sums:
$$E(p)=\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(2^k-1)p(1-p)^{(k-1)}=p\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}2^k(1-p)^{k-1} - p\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{k-1}  \\ = 2p\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{k}(1-p)^{k} - p \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(1-p)^{k}$$
The sum $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{k}(1-p)^{k} $ is convergent only, if $p>\frac{1}{2}$. For $p \leq 2$ we have $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{k}(1-p)^{k} =\infty $
The second sum is equal $\frac{1}{p}$ for any $p\neq 0$

Therefore we have:
$$E(p)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2p-1}, & p>\frac{1}{2}\\
\infty,& p\leq \frac{1}{2}\end{cases}$$

Comment: many thanks, just one question, why is it defined for p=1/2? i get that it diverges as p approaches 1/2, can we therefor say its infinity at P=1/2?

Comment: @Ang for $p=1/2$ we have $\sum 1$, which is definitely $\infty$

Comment: ok i see, i was just asking bc it would become 0 in the denominator...., but i see now - many thanks!

Comment: You could simplify $\frac{2p}{2p-1}-1$ to just $\frac1{2p-1}$.